# Links em rollover do menu não funcionam

Tags: css

Tenho um problema com o meu menu que consiste em links com imagens que são substituídas por outros quando em *mouseover*.

Fiz um snippet para que possam ver o problema. Se repararem, tirei o `text-indent` aos dois últimos links do menu e assim já funcionam embora fique sem o efeito *rollover* e nos três primeiros links os *rollovers* funcionam, mas os links não.

```css
.bg {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    img.bg {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px;
    }
}

#video-wrapper1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 700px;
    top: 100px;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: #0073ff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition-property: width, height;
    transition-duration: .2s;
    transition-timing-function: linear; 
}

#video-wrapper1:hover {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px; 
}

nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav a#pull {
    display: none;
}

nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul {
    width: 260px;
    height: 40px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav ul {
    display: none;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav a#pull:after {
        content: "";
        background: url('../imagens/icon_nav.png') no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
}

nav ul li:hover:nth-child(1) {
   background: url('http://s33.postimg.org/sokmmh4lr/Logo_hover.png') no-repeat;
   text-indent: 99999px;
   margin-right: 14px;
   display: block;
   width: 50px;
   height: 46px;
}

nav ul li:hover:nth-child(2) {
   background: url('http://s33.postimg.org/f74u19jtb/fb_logo2.png') no-repeat;
   display: block;
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   position: relative;
   margin-right: 14px;
   text-indent: 99999px;
}

nav ul li:hover:nth-child(3) {
   background: url('http://s33.postimg.org/hrhgs7m33/twitter.png') no-repeat;
   display: block;
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   position: relative;
   margin-right: 14px;
   text-indent: -99999px;
}

nav ul li:hover:nth-child(4) {
   background: url('http://s33.postimg.org/eehydlqbz/youtube_logo.jpg') no-repeat;
   display: block;
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   position: relative;
   margin-right: 14px;
}

nav ul li:hover:nth-child(5) {
   background: url('http://s33.postimg.org/foxos8wpb/logo_ulht.gif') no-repeat;
   display: block;
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   position: relative;
   margin-right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

        <title>Projecto Aurora</title>
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/video.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <body>
        <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/3ueeqpuhb/Fundo.png" class="bg" alt="Lisboa" >
        
        <nav class="clearfix"> 
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="index.html"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/697nx9pjj/Logo.png" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/cgsp8agzz/fb_logo_BK.png" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/5owb5kntb/twitter_BK.png" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/ewtlje173/youtube_logo_BK.png" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/jlndjsuj3/logo_ulht_BK.png" alt=""/></a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" id="pull"></a>
        </nav>
        
        <div id="video-wrapper1">   
            <iframe id="video1" width="200" height="169" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Inufy4FdnRk"
            frameborder="0" style="display:none" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Ao usar `text-indent` você está movendo o link para a direita, para fora da tela inclusive.
Tente usar de início a imagem como background

```
<li><a href="index.html"></a></li>
```

css

```
nav ul li:nth-child(1) {
    background: url('http://s33.postimg.org/697nx9pjj/Logo.png') no-   repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 46px;
    margin-right: 14px;
}
nav ul li:hover:nth-child(1) {
    background: url('http://s33.postimg.org/sokmmh4lr/Logo_hover.png') no-   repeat;
}
```